# Using GSON to parse a JSON array and Object

Tags: java, json, object, gson

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
 "waypoints": [
    {
        "waypoint_index": 0,
        "trips_index": 0,
        "hint": "u_FYj4uKI=",
        "name": "",
        "location": [
            28.068655,
            41.180774
        ]
    },
    {
        "waypoint_index": 4,
        "trips_index": 0,
        "hint": "KiKhg4uKI=",
        "name": "",
        "location": [
            20.75179,
            29.031869
        ]
    }
}
```

I know if you want to create java objects, well, you have just to understand how JSON works.

```
{} -> object

[] -> array
```

but I could not!

How to convert Java object to This json file?

```
public class ResultOsrm {
    public Waypoints waypoints;
}

public class Waypoints {
    public List waypoint_index;

}
```

Main -

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();                             
ResultOsrm resultOsrm=gson.fromJson(JsonFile,ResultOsrm.class); 
System.out.println(resultOsrm);
```

I need just waypoint_index and location values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ResultOsrm` should hold list of `Waypoint` and class `Waypoint` will hold the data

```
public class ResultOsrm
{
    public List<Waypoint> waypoints;
}

public class Waypoint
{
    public int waypoint_index;
    public int trips_index;
    public String hint;
    public String name;
    public List<float> location;
}
```

`waypoint_index` is a variable in `Waypoint`, not a list by itself.

Comment: thnx a lot @Guy! it's run.

Answer (score 1):

Use Kotlin to define the data classes.

***WayPoint.kt***

```
data class WayPoint(
    @SerializedName("waypoint_index") var wayPointIndex: String,
    @SerializedName("trips_index") var tripIndex: String,
    @SerializedName("hint") var hint: String,
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String,
    @SerializedName("location") var location: ArrayList<String>
```

)

***Response.kt***

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("waypoints") var wayPoints: ArrayList<WayPoint>
```

)

**then to convert the string to JSON and to objects in Java class**

```
    String data = "{\n" +
            " \"waypoints\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"waypoint_index\": 0,\n" +
            "        \"trips_index\": 0,\n" +
            "        \"hint\": \"u_FYj4uKI=\",\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"\",\n" +
            "        \"location\": [\n" +
            "            28.068655,\n" +
            "            41.180774\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"waypoint_index\": 4,\n" +
            "        \"trips_index\": 0,\n" +
            "        \"hint\": \"KiKhg4uKI=\",\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"\",\n" +
            "        \"location\": [\n" +
            "            20.75179,\n" +
            "            29.031869\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "\t]\n" +
            "}";

    Response response = new Gson().fromJson(
            data,
            Response.class
    );
```

The response class has all your data converted to the data class values.

Do try this solution. this will surely solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As the **Sagar Nayak** mentioned above is correct.

> Kotlin

if you want to convert mockup data to ArrayList you could use this. It is the other options in case of you don't want to create a model, which contains ArrayList attribute within.

```
// when json variable is your mockup data

val list= Gson().fromJson<ArrayList<WayPoint>>(json, Array<WayPoint>::class.java).toCollection(ArrayList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON structure is little incorrect here -

```
{
     "waypoints": [
        {
            "waypoint_index": 0,
            "trips_index": 0,
            "hint": "u_FYj4uKI=",
            "name": "",
            "location": [
                28.068655,
                41.180774
            ]
        },
        {
            "waypoint_index": 4,
            "trips_index": 0,
            "hint": "KiKhg4uKI=",
            "name": "",
            "location": [
                20.75179,
                29.031869
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You don't have closing array bracket for `waypoints`.

Also, you need to modify your class structure as per the JSON -

```
public class ResultOsrm {
    private List<Waypoints> waypointsList;
    // getter setter
}

public class Waypoints {
    private Integer waypoint_index;
    private List<Double> location;
    // other fields & all getter setters

}
```

You should map every fields into objects & then use whatever you need out of it.

> Note - Make your instance variable private & provide getters & setters
>   for fields. This is a good practice to have in POJO classes.